# How to remove the blank space in the function in latex?

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{etex}   
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\algblockdefx[Foreach]{Foreach}{EndForeach}[1]{\textbf{for all} #1 
\textbf{do}}{\textbf{end for}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicindent{.75em}%
\algdef{SE}[FUNCTION]{Function}{EndFunction}%
[2]{\algorithmicfunction\ \textproc{#1}\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{(#2)}}%
{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfunction}%
\newfloat{function}{htbp}{loa}
\floatname{function}{Function} %It may be done better
%def\NoNumber#1{{\def\alglinenumber##1{}\State #1}\addtocounter{ALG@line}
%{-1}}
\begin{function}    
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]  
    \State\Function{FunctionName}{$R$}
    \Statex{\textit{// Comments}}
    \Foreach{$i \in R$}
    \State $\lambda_i$ $\gets$ $r_i$.firstFunction();       
    \EndForeach
    \Foreach{ $i \in R$ }
    \State R $\gets$ $\lambda_i$.secondFunction()
    \EndForeach     
    \State \Return R
    \EndFunction 
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{xyz}
\end{function}
\end{document}
```

How remove the first blank space in the output of the given code?

Comment: Can you please make your code compilable? And can you describe which space you want to remove? And why is the questions tagges with `biblatex`?

Comment: I have made the code compilable.  The output of this code is a function in which all the steps are being numbered from 1 to 10. I am getting step 1 as blank. I want to remove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\Statex` instead of `\State`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{etex}   
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\algblockdefx[Foreach]{Foreach}{EndForeach}[1]{\textbf{for all} #1 
\textbf{do}}{\textbf{end for}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicindent{.75em}%
\algdef{SE}[FUNCTION]{Function}{EndFunction}%
[2]{\algorithmicfunction\ \textproc{#1}\ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{(#2)}}%
{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicfunction}%
\newfloat{function}{htbp}{loa}
\floatname{function}{Function} %It may be done better
%def\NoNumber#1{{\def\alglinenumber##1{}\State #1}\addtocounter{ALG@line}
%{-1}}
\begin{function}    
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]  
    \Statex\Function{FunctionName}{$R$}
    \Statex{\textit{// Comments}}
    \Foreach{$i \in R$}
    \State $\lambda_i$ $\gets$ $r_i$.firstFunction();       
    \EndForeach
    \Foreach{ $i \in R$ }
    \State R $\gets$ $\lambda_i$.secondFunction()
    \EndForeach     
    \State \Return R
    \EndFunction 
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{xyz}
\end{function}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

You can just remove \State or \Statex altogether and get the desired result.

Comment: Hello JPi, thanks for your reply but still I am not getting what you have changed in the code. I have copied-pasted your code but still the output is same.

Comment: I'm sorry: I still had your code in the buffer.  See \Statex immediately following \begin{algorithmic}?

Comment: Note the edit: you don't need the \State or \Statex in front of \Function at all.,

Comment: Is there anyway to start the numbering after the comment statement and remove the numbering before that.

Comment: I'm sure that there is, but I'm not familiar with this package.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62936/discussion-between-yogesh-sharma-and-jpi).